# Secure and Nonsecure Dynamic Updates

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7

Domain Controller: Windows Server 2008 R2

Client: Windows 7

For the past 3-4 days, I was trying to register some client desktops / laptops to get their DNS entry dynamically by various methods such as `ipconfig /registerdns` & re-adding to domain.

Still they didn't get registered with the DC (DNS manager). In the DNS, `Dynamic updates` is set to `Secure only` (It is an Active Directory Integrated Zone).

For testing, I changed the `Dynamic update` to `Nonsecure and Secure` and after running `ipconfig /registerdns`, it gets registered.

I don't understand why it doesn't get registered when `Dynamic update` is set to `Secure only`.

I know `Secure only` means it will register and update only if it gets authenticated.

But my question is the client desktop / laptop is already joined to a Domain and I also re-joined to the domain. Still it doesn't get registered in DNS (when `Dynamic update` is set to `Secure only`)

It's a security risk if I keep `Dynamic update` set to to `Nonsecure and Secure`.

Comment: Is it only happening with this client?

Comment: What's the DNS record for that client look like?  Does the client successfully register in secure only more if you manually remove all existing DNS entries for its name, then have it register?

Comment: @Danila Lader - No.

Comment: @Param, do you also have deployed a Microsoft DHCP? Beside of that, you should check ACLs for those registers that do not updates.

Comment: @SantiFdezMunoz. No, we haven't deployed a Microsoft DHCP. I can't Check ACLs, because the registration don't take place

Answer (score 1):

To have Secure Dynamic Updates you have to use Microsoft DHCP Service, which is Authorized in your domain. Then DHCP service will update your DNS records automatically.